# ion-content scrolling stopped working on ios 14

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, capacitor

My app stopped working some screens right after iOS 14.0 update, when I test on an 13.5 emulator it is working normally.

I'm already using the following code:

```
ion-app.platform-ios12 ion-content {
   pointer-events: auto; / * fix scroll lock on ios12.2 * /
}
```

and I also tried to force the screen to scroll by css, but no news :(

Has anyone faced a similar situation? Any leads would help!
My settings:

```
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.8 
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
Capacitor:
   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.2
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.2
System:
   npm    : 6.14.8
   OS     : macOS Catalina
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guys I've figured it out, apparently my project contained an SCSS class that had a problem in the following items:

```
.background {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1; <--------------- PROBLEM
  transition-property: none;
  transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0px);
}
```

After removing the top: 0 and the z-index, the scrolling of the screen returned to work.
What I found the most strange is that in iOS version 13.x it worked smoothly. But okay, the important thing is that it worked again ;)

Comment: Thanks. I have removed z-index: -1 and it started working in 14

Answer (score 4):

You need to update your code to point to iOS 14 like this

`ion-app.platform-ios14 ion-content { pointer-events: auto;  }`

Answer (score 0):

This works on **Ionic 3** project

`variables.scss`

```
ion-app.platform-ios14 ion-content { 
          pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```